# Airflow - No named module microsoft providers

Tags: airflow

I am new to airflow and using version 1.10.12

I have created a DAG to connect to Azure Data Lake and copy files from there to GCS. However, I keep getting this error message e. The python code anywhere is not referring Azure. How to solve this error?

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the source code of the DAG? Also what exact command did you use to install Airflow (or to be more specific, what extras did you install)

Answer (score 0):

If you connect Azure Data Lake with GCS you definitely have some `import` like `from azure.*** import ***`. It seems like you didn't install the package for azure properly.

Try [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/index.html#installation) documentation to see how you can install that package.